# Making a zmq server run forever in Django?

Tags: python, django, celery, zeromq

I'm trying to figure that best way to keep a zeroMQ listener running forever in my django app.

I'm setting up a zmq server app in my Django project that acts as internal API to other applications in our network (no need to go through http/requests stuff since these apps are internal). I want the zmq listener inside of my django project to always be alive.

I want the zmq listener in my Django project so I have access to all of the projects models (for querying) and other django context things.

I'm currently thinking:

- Set up a Django management command that will run the listener and keep it alive forever (aka infinite loop inside the zmq listener code) or
- use a celery worker to always keep the zmq listener alive? But I'm not exactly sure on how to get a celery worker to restart a task only if it's not running. All the celery docs are about frequency/delayed running. Or maybe I should let celery purge the task @ a given interval & restart it anyways..

Any tips, advice on performance implications or alternate approaches?

Comment: Your first choice looks like the way to go for me: having a dedicated process to manage the zeromq socket (while the Django process handle the HTTP requests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up a management command is a fine way to do this, especially if you're running on your own hardware.

If you're running in a cloud, where a machine may disappear along with your process, then the latter is a better option. This is how I've done it:

1. Setup a periodic task that runs every N seconds (you need celerybeat running somewhere)
2. When the task spawns, it first checks a shared network resource (redis, zookeeper, or a db), to see if another process has an active/valid [lease](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lease_%28computer_science%29). If one exists, abort.
3. If there's no valid lease, obtain your lease (beware of concurrency here!), and start your  infinite loop, making sure you periodically renew the lease.
4. Add instrumentation so that you know who, where the process is running.
5. Start celery workers on multiple boxes, consuming from the same queue your periodic task is designated for.

The second solution is more complex and harder to get right; so if you can, a singleton is great and consider using something like supervisord to ensure the process gets restarted if it faults for some reason.

Comment: I created a management command, I think that is much simpler after looking into ways of implementing it using celery. Thanks for the cloud explanation though, I just may use it someday!

Comment: No need for a periodic task. Set up a daemon process instead. This has many advantages, like using pidfiles and monitor it by something like Monit.